# Does /dev, /run and /sys exist on HDD (if so what is there location if it can be meaningfully traced)?

Tags: filesystems, mount, ext4, proc, systemd-run

At the time of Linux installation, i have mentioned only one filesystem (/dev/sda1 -> ext4 -> / ). But for dev, run, proc, sys - Linux is creating addition FS which is inferable from `mount`.

```
$ mount
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=12138104k,nr_inodes=3034526,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=2433824k,mode=755)
/dev/sda4 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
...
```

I am aware that /proc is a Virtual FS and is in memory and not on any HDD/SSD. Could some one explain what is the case with /dev, /run and /sys. Do they exist on HDD (if so what is there location if it can be meaningfully traced).

Based on already asked Q - [Why inode numbers of /dev and /run are same as that of /?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/607640/why-inode-numbers-of-dev-and-run-are-same-as-that-of)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where does tmpfs come from and how is it mounted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/522694/where-does-tmpfs-come-from-and-how-is-it-mounted)

Comment: And also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/236533/sysfs-and-devtmpfs - "sysfs is a ram-based filesystem", "Devtmpfs lets the kernel create a tmpfs instance called devtmpfs"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `mount` output lists the file system types:

- `/dev` is a `devtmpfs` (a virtual file system exporting device nodes)
- `/run` is a [`tmpfs`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/tmpfs.5.html) (a virtual memory file system)
- `/sys` is a [`sysfs`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sysfs.5.html) (a virtual file system exporting kernel objects)

All of these live in memory, not on your drives. `man 5 proc tmpfs sysfs` will show you the documentation for these, or you can follow the links above.